# pyodbc.connect() works, but not sqlalchemy.create_engine().connect()

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am attempting to write a Python script that can take Excel sheets and import them into my SQL Server Express (with Windows Authentication) database as tables. To do this, I am using `pandas` to read the Excel files into a `pandas DataFrame`, I then hope to use `pandas.to_sql()` to import the data into my database. To use this function, however, I need to use `sqlalchemy.create_engine()`.

I am able to connect to my database using `pyodbc` alone, and run test queries. This conection is done with the followng code:

```
def create_connection(server_name, database_name):
    config = dict(server=server_name, database= database_name)

    conn_str = ('SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes')

    return pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};' + conn_str.format(**config))

...

server = '<MY_SERVER_NAME>\SQLEXPRESS'
db = '<MY_DATABASE_NAME>

connection = create_connection(server, db)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT * FROM existing_table')
cursor.commit()
```

However, this isn't much use as I can't use `pandas.to_sql()` - to do so I need an engine from `sqlalchemy.create_engine()`, but I am struggling to figure out how to use my same details in my `create_connection()` function above to successfully create an engine and connect to the database.

I have tried many, many combinations along the lines of:

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@C<MY_SERVER_NAME>\SQLEXPRESS/<MY_DATABASE_NAME>?driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}?trusted_connection=yes")
conn = engine.connect().connection
```

or

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@C<MY_SERVER_NAME>\SQLEXPRESS/<MY_DATABASE_NAME>?trusted_connection=yes")   
conn = engine.connect().connection
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A [Pass through exact Pyodbc string](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string) works for me:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_string = (
    r"Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    r"Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;"
    r"Database=myDb;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
)
connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc", 
    query={"odbc_connect": connection_string}
)
engine = create_engine(connection_url)

df = pd.DataFrame([(1, "foo")], columns=["id", "txt"])
pd.to_sql("test_table", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Comment: why are we using the quote_plus()?

Comment: Answer updated to use sqlalchemy.engine.URL

Comment: thanks you for this.

Any idea why constructing the connection this way works as opposed to the one used in the question?

Comment: `URL.create()` takes care of escaping characters that can cause problems in a plain string URL. The most common is '@' in a password.