# SQL Server connection - Works in pyodbc, but not SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

This is a fairly common question but even using the answers on SO [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760221/pyodbc-connect-works-but-not-sqlalchemy-create-engine-connect?rq=1) but I still can't connect.

When I setup my connection to `pyodbc` I can connect with the following:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=ip,port;DATABASE=db;UID=user;PWD=pass')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("some select query")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

**and it works.**

However to do a `.read_sql()` in `pandas` I need to connect with `sqlalchemy`.

I have tried with both hosted connections and pass-through pyodbc connections like the below:

```
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=ip;Database=db;UID=user;PWD=pass;Port=port;')
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
engine.connect()
```

I have tried with both `SERVER=ip,port` format and the separate `Port=port` parameter like above but still no luck.

The error I'm getting is `Login failed for user 'user'. (18456)`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which edition of sqlserver you have installed? I have been facing many connection related issues and then I realized the culprit was the edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to create a *DataFrame* so when you have a `cnxn` you can pass it to *Pandas* `read_sql_query` function.
Example:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('your connection string')
query = 'some query'

df = pandas.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```